# Always get an accuracy and recall of 1.0 before and after oversampling

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, logistic-regression, random-forest

I have the wine dataset, I removed nulls, normalized the dataset. and then created a new column called Quality, if the quality score is over 0.7 then its good, if its below then its a bad wine.  I just wanted to try binary classification.

I tried Logistic Regression with the unbalanced data set and I get this:

```
[[418   0]
 [  0  60]]
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      1.00      1.00       418
           1       1.00      1.00      1.00        60

    accuracy                           1.00       478
   macro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00       478
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00       478
```

SO I resampled with SMOTE and tried RandomForestClassifier and I get this:

```
Accuracy = 1.00
Recall = 1.00
```

I really doubt this is possible

What am I doing wrong?

Full code below:

```
df.dropna(how='any', inplace=True)
df.isnull().sum()

#normalize
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
names = df.columns
d = scaler.fit_transform(df)
scaled_df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=names)
scaled_df.head()

# Count unique values for the quality score.
scaled_df['quality'].value_counts()


Output menu
0.4    679
0.6    636
0.8    197
0.2     53
1.0     18
0.0     10
Name: quality, dtype: int64


#adding new column
conditions = [
    (scaled_df['quality'] <= 0.7),
    (scaled_df['quality'] >0.7)
    ]

values = [0, 1]

scaled_df['QualityLabel'] = np.select(conditions, values)
scaled_df

# We can use value counts
scaled_df['QualityLabel'].value_counts()

# or we can separate the classes and then print the shape 
class_0 = scaled_df[scaled_df['QualityLabel'] == 0]
class_1 = scaled_df[scaled_df['QualityLabel'] == 1]# print the shape of the class
print('class 0:', class_0.shape)
print('class 1:', class_1.shape)

class 0: (1378, 13)
class 1: (215, 13)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(scaled_df, scaled_df["QualityLabel"], test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
np.bincount(y_train)

# now we have 2 bins, 960 for training and 155 for testing.y_train.head(10)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
#Initalize the classifier
clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0)
#Fitting the training data
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
#Predicting on test
y_pred=clf.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))

#lets resample with SMOTE

from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE 

sm = SMOTE(random_state=42)

X_sm, y_sm = sm.fit_resample(scaled_df,  scaled_df["QualityLabel"])

print(f'''Shape of X before SMOTE: {scaled_df.shape}
Shape of X after SMOTE: {X_sm.shape}''')

print('\nBalance of positive and negative classes (%):')
y_sm.value_counts(normalize=True) * 100

Output menu
Shape of X before SMOTE: (1593, 13)
Shape of X after SMOTE: (2756, 13)

Balance of positive and negative classes (%):
0    50.0
1    50.0
Name: QualityLabel, dtype: float64

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, recall_score, confusion_matrix


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X_sm, y_sm, test_size=0.25, random_state=42
)

model = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
preds = model.predict(X_test)

print(f'Accuracy = {accuracy_score(y_test, preds):.2f}\nRecall = {recall_score(y_test, preds):.2f}\n')
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, preds)
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.title('Confusion Matrix (with SMOTE)', size=16)
sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, cmap='Blues');
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, you did not drop the label `Quality` or `QualityLabel` from your features. If these are still among your features, then predicting the label will be 100% since it is exactly your label.

Let's remove the columns that are your labels:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

df = pd.read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv",sep=";")

df.dropna(how='any', inplace=True)
df.isnull().sum()

d = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(df)
scaled_df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=df.columns)
scaled_df['QualityLabel'] = np.where(scaled_df['quality']>=0.7,1,0)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(scaled_df.drop(['QualityLabel','quality'],axis=1), scaled_df["QualityLabel"], test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
```

Fit the model:

```
clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred=clf.predict(X_test)
```

And you can see the confusion matrix makes more sense now:

```
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))

[[420  10]
 [ 39  11]]
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.92      0.98      0.94       430
           1       0.52      0.22      0.31        50

    accuracy                           0.90       480
   macro avg       0.72      0.60      0.63       480
weighted avg       0.87      0.90      0.88       480
```